# como sumo esta variable?

Tags: python

se que es algo simple pero hice este codigo para un ejercicio en donde tengo que diseñar un codigo que pida el nombre y precio de un producto y almacene estas variables luego pregunte si tienes mas productos por registrar si si tiene seguir preguntando el codigo y si no tiene sumar todas los precios de los productos

```
    def caja():
     contador=True
     total=0
     while contador==True:
        n1=input("ponga el nombre del producto: ")
        n2=int(input("ponga el precio del producto: ")) 
        total+=n2 
        def imprimaProducto():
            nombre=n1
            producto=total
            print("el producto es " + str(nombre))
            print("el precio es "+ str(producto))

        imprimaProducto()

        repetir=input("tiene mas articulos por registrar?")
        if repetir=="si":
            caja()
        elif repetir=="no":
            contador=False

    return print(total)     

caja()
```

Comment: La pregunta necesita clarificación. ¿Qué es lo que falla? Sugerencia: en lugar de escribir `contador == True` puedes escribir `contador`. Y la variable contador contiene un valor lógico, no un número. Sería más descriptivo nombrarla `seguir` o algo así. Otra cosa, la mayor parte de tu código está dentro del ciclo, lo que significa que se repetirá siempre que la condición sea verdadera. No necesitas llamar nuevamente a la función`caja`, solo estás haciendo el código más complicado.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está poco claro, pero sospecho que lo que sucede es que no podés conseguir el total de precios que querés. Elegiste modelar esto como una función recursiva y eso no está mal, el problema es que cuando llamás a caja dentro de caja, en ningún lado estás devolviendo el valor total para ir acumulandolo. Para solucionar esto, deberías quitar el `return print(total)`
y cambiarlo por `return total`.

Una vez hecho esto, faltaría que cuando volvés a llamar a `caja()` (recursión) asignes la suma. Por último, como tu función la planteas como recursiva te sobra el `while True` del principio. Te propongo el código modificado, probalo y me contás

```
def caja():
    total=0
    #while contador==True:
    n1 = input("ponga el nombre del producto: ")
    n2 = int(input("ponga el precio del producto: ")) 
    total+=n2 
    def imprimaProducto():
        nombre = n1
        producto = total
        print("el producto es " + str(nombre))
        print("el precio es "+ str(producto))

    imprimaProducto()

    repetir=input("tiene mas articulos por registrar?")
    if repetir=="si":
        total += caja() #aca modifique
    elif repetir=="no":
        contador=False

    return total  #y acá
```